# Inventory management using exception handling

Tags: java

I am doing a project on Inventory management. I want to input the Customer name from the user and it cannot be null/blank( exception handling)  Quantity needs to be validated from the inventory( exception handling). how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

i write example for quantity: or you can use regular expression java.

When user gives string instead of number you will get arithmetic exception on stack trace.

```
try {
int num=Integer.parseInt ("XYZ") ; 

}catch(ArithmeticException e){
System.out.println(e)
}cath(nullpointerException e){

System.out.println(e)
```

}

read this tutorial to learn exception handling
http://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/java-exception-handling/